# Recurrence for the viabin numbers of the self-conjugate integer partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, special-functions, recurrences, oeis

Let $a(n)$ be [A290254](http://oeis.org/A290254), the viabin numbers of the self-conjugate integer partitions, also defined as $\left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$ union fixed points of [A059894](http://oeis.org/A059894), self-inverse permutation defined as follows:

> Complement and reverse the order of all but the most significant bit in binary expansion of $n$. $n = 1ab\cdots yz$ -> $1ZY\cdots BA = A059894(n)$, where $A = 1-a, B = 1-b, \cdots$

I conjecture that
$$a(n) = \begin{cases}
n-1,&\text{if $n < 3$}\\
a(n-1) + 2\cdot 4^{f(n-1) - 1} + 3\cdot 2^{f(n-1) - 1} - 1,&\text{if $n = 2^k + 1, k > 0$}\\
a(n-1) + (2^{g(n-1) + 2} - 3)\cdot 2^{f(h(n-2))},&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where

- $f(n)$ is [A000523](http://oeis.org/A000523), $f(n) = \left\lfloor\log_2(n)\right\rfloor$
- $g(n)$ is [A007814](http://oeis.org/A007814), exponent of highest power of $2$ dividing $n$, a.k.a. the binary carry sequence, the ruler sequence, or the $2$-adic valuation of $n$.
- $h(n)$ is [A025480](http://oeis.org/A025480), $h(2n) = n, h(2n+1) = h(n)$

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: This should follow straightforwardly from the characterisation that $a(2^k + m)$ with $1 \le m \le 2^k$ is given by $4^k + 2^k (m-1) + \operatorname{revinv}_k(m-1)$ where $\operatorname{revinv}_k$ reverses and inverts the bits of a $k$-bit number.